# Google Chrome в приложении Win forms

Tags: c#, google-chrome, winforms

Пишу приложение на С#, в котором хотелось бы увидеть браузер crome для использования google speech. Использовал awesomium, которым открыл страницу но google speech он не поддерживает. Т.е. Нужен именно хром в моем приложении. Может кто сталкивался с подобным. Заранее спасибо

Comment: ну или на крайняк это: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/462191/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12232784/4928642

Answer (score 2):

[How to develop Desktop Apps using HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232784/how-to-develop-desktop-apps-using-html-css-javascript)
Перевод [принятого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12234577/4928642):

Можно начать с Titanium'а для десктопной разработки. Также стоит обратить внимание на **[chromiumembedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/)**. Это по сути контрол веб-браузера, основанного на хромиуме.

Он написан на C++ и позволяет использовать все низкоуровневые возможности ОС (Growl, иконки в трее, доступ к локальным файлам, com-порты и т. д.) и при этом писать всю логику и интерфейс приложения на html и javascript. Он также позволяет перехватывать любые http-запросы, чтобы обратится к локальным ресурсам или выполнить особые действия. Например, запрос на http://localapp.com/SetTrayIconState?state=active может быть перехвачен контейнером, который вызовет код на Си++ чтобы обновить иконку в трее.

Он позволяет создавать функции, которые могут непосредственно вызываться из js.

Но в CEF очень сложно отлаживать js. Там нет ничего похожего на Firebug.

Ещё можно посетить **[AppJS.com](http://appjs.com/)** (Помогает создавать десктопные приложения под Linux, Windows и Mac используя HTML, CSS и JavaScript).

Как дополнил @Clint, команда Bracket.io (Adobe) используя Chromium Embedded Framework создала замечательную оболочку. Она называется [brackets shell](http://github.com/adobe/brackets-shell). Также доступно [её описание](http://clintberry.com/2013/html5-desktop-apps-with-brackets-shell).

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, [это](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/) или [вот это](https://github.com/mono/webkit-sharp) будет вам полезно

Comment: Спасибо, но мне все же кажется что в веб ките не будет поддержка того что мне надо, а именно google speech

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver под кучу языков идет на ура.
Из личного опыта я с ним работаю больше года в Visual Basic 2008