# Как использовать веб-технологии для создания десктоп-приложений?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Какие технологии использовать для разработки приложений на HTML5/CSS/Javascript под Windows, OS X, Linux?

Например для разработки телефонных приложений можно использовать Apache Cordova. А мне нужно разработать приложения под десктопные ОС.

Comment: _"кроссплатформенных"_ -- о каких платформах говорите? javascript работает в разных браузерах одинаково.

Comment: Я имею ввиду не браузер. А приложения. Например для разработки телефонных приложений можно использовать Apache Cordova. А вот  приложения которые будут работать на ПК с Mac и Unix

Comment: Под Windows/Mac/Linux – посмотрите [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468164/178988

Comment: Возможно вам стоит построить единую бекенд архитектуру и переносить ее под проекты, пользуясь у каждой платформы только возможностями GUI

Comment: Electron, nw.js - те же html, css, js крутятся в каждой платформе одинаково